# How to fit 10 images in a full screen row for any resolution maintaining 4:3 aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

Hi i want to fit 10 images into a full screen width row maintaining `4:3` aspect ratio

**Question:** i want to fit exactly 10 images into a full width row keeping aspect ratio `4:3` of images

**Note:** my use case is for **storyboard** which will not have any spacing between images

here is how my current code rendering

[image]

here is what i have tried

```css
ul {
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100vw;height:71px;border:1px solid red;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

please help me thanks in advance!!

Comment: are the images themselves always going to be a 4:3 aspect ratio? Or they could be any aspect ratio but you'd just like to display them in a 4:3 cropped frame?

Comment: Is height fixed `height:71px;` or it will increase or decrease according to aspect ratio 4:3?

Comment: @RaeeshAlam height will be fixed to `71px`  but `width` can vary till large monitor size

Comment: @diopside my manager put that requirement to have aspect ratio of `4:3` as in `transcoding` part aspect ratio is maintained like that  with images grater than `400x20..` above  therefore i have started bounty as i don't know how to achieve that

Answer (score 7):

You can use `grid` property for `ul`, `aspect-ratio` for `li` and `object-fit` property for `img`:

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.root {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
          />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <h3 style="margin-top: 24px; margin-bottom: 0;">if you just set width: 100% for image</h3>
    <div class="root">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
            style="height: unset"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
            style="height: unset"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
            style="height: unset"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
            style="height: unset"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
            style="height: unset"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
            style="height: unset"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
            style="height: unset"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
            style="height: unset"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
            style="height: unset"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"
            style="height: unset"
          />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: solution looks good, but spacing between images is not required

Comment: you are right. I just wanted to show the difference between the two solutions

Comment: @EaBengaluru I edited my `css` code and now there is no space between images

Comment: good solution wrt to fitting the container + 1 for that

Answer (score 5):

You can use `aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;` property and for image need to use `object-fit: cover;` property for cover the size of `li` element.

**2nd Scope:** If you remove `height: 71px;` from parent element then each image will render as aspect-ratio: 4:3
**Helpful Link:**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    width: 10%;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
    aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100vw; height: 71px; border:1px solid red;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br>
If you remove `height: 71px;` from parent element then each image will render as aspect-ratio: 4:3
<div style="width:100vw; border:1px solid red;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: with this big image https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png  your code should maintain aspect ratio of `4:3`

Comment: see my update code now

Comment: If you want to maintain aspect ratio `4:3` then you need to remove parent `height: 71px`,  so Run this snippet and check bottom row of images.

Comment: @EaBengaluru `li` height will vary if you want as aspect ratio `4:3`. If  `li` width increase/decrease as large/small screen size then height will auto maintain so you can't define fixed height. Or you need `fixed height` then image will render as `4:3` but bottom side will show gap on small screen.

Comment: 2nd example is also not working properly if i check in **Full page** view it is rendering something as `2.5X2` i guess check here https://ibb.co/Cs5TB01

Comment: @EaBengaluru Check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyDkC.png and Calculate widhtxheight as `4:3` from https://calculateaspectratio.com/

Comment: I understood , very good explanation !!!

Comment: @EaBengaluru :-) thanks for appreciation.

Answer (score 3):

Here I have removed `height: 71px;` from parent element and add one div above the image.

and here I have used `padding-top: 75%`(4:3) instead of aspect-ratio property.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul {
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    width: 10%;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.aspect-ratio-4by3 {
   position: relative;
   padding-top: 75%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100vw; border:1px solid red;">
    <ul>
       <li>
          <div class="aspect-ratio-4by3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="aspect-ratio-4by3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="aspect-ratio-4by3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="aspect-ratio-4by3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="aspect-ratio-4by3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="aspect-ratio-4by3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="aspect-ratio-4by3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="aspect-ratio-4by3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="aspect-ratio-4by3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="aspect-ratio-4by3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
          </div>
        </li>
       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your height is fixed to `71px` then width has to be `95px` to maintain the aspect ratio 4:3.
We nee to fix parents, `li`, size to 95 x 71px and stretch images to fit in it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #container {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 71px;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
      ul {
        height: 100%;
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      li {
        width: 95px; /* fix the width */
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
      }

      img {
        aspect-ratio: 4/3;
        object-fit: fill; /* fit the content in 95 x 71 box */
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit/mdn_logo_only_color.png"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/plumeria.jpg"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you put any image in it, it'll stretch to fit in 95x71px box. So for any image the browser will show aspect ratio 95:71 which is ~ 4:3.

---

Evenly spaced content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #container {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 71px;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
      ul {
        height: 100%;
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
      }

      li {
        width: 95px; /* fix the width */
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      img {
        aspect-ratio: 4/3;
        object-fit: fill; /* fit the content in 95 x 71 box */
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit/mdn_logo_only_color.png"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/plumeria.jpg"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's correct but does not fit whole container

Comment: You can put space between images to span over entire screen width. See the updated answer 'evenly spaced content' part.  But you can't increase image width itself, it'll violate aspect ratio 4:3.

Comment: i have seen your 2nd example too,it looks good.  But my use case was `timeline` you might have seen it in video editing software. if i give gap it will not be useful.

Comment: I see. But in video editing software timeline is left empty if there are no enough clips, like in my first example. If you show me image of any video software time line you are trying to replicate I'll get better idea.

Comment: In following image the remaining timeline is empty: https://img.indezine.com/v7/https://notes.indezine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Timeline-in-EaseUS-Video-Editor.png?w=1200&h=715.5&org_if_sml=1

Comment: cool +1 for showing that

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `aspect-ratio` property and `background-image` property.

1. `aspect-ratio`

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  width: 10%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid red;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

2.`background-image`

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  width: 10%;
  padding-top: 7.5%;
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid red;">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is 2nd code run result.
[image: 2nd code run result]

As you can see, image `width` is **61.5px**, and `height` is **46.125px**.
Aspect ratio is **4:3**.

Comment: FYI your 1st code is not maintaining aspect ratio of `4:3` 2nd code is maintaining `16:9` hd aspect ratio

Comment: @EaBengaluru, which browser do you use?

Comment: @EaBengaluru, `10%: 7.5%` is equal to `4:3`.

Comment: @EaBengaluru, I edited my answer. As you can see, aspect ratio is 4:3.

Comment: ok cool +1 for that..

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width:10%;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 75%;

}
```

```html
<div style="width:100vw;height:71px;border:1px solid red;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/N1nyZZb/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

use width 10% for split into 10 phase and for 4:3 ratio change  img css max-height:75% & max-width:100%

Comment: Actually my use case for **storyboard** which will not have any spacing between images

Comment: Your image is `1:1` aspect-ratio.

Comment: if you don't want spacing just add another css madding:0px and margin:0px; so it will remove the extra spacing.

Comment: or else you can use fixed width and height for the image

Comment: and use overflow:hidden css property also

Answer (score -1):

```css
ul {
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100vw;height:71px;border:1px solid red;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/qy7h4qk/Screenshot-from-2021-10-15-12-09-31.png"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jgofdg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).